# Can I call a Silverlight service from an Android application?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

I have a Silverlight business application and a WCF Service developed in it. I used to call it from a Windows Phone application under Visual Studio 2010. 
Is there a way I can call this service from an android application developed under Visual Studio 2010 or from Xamarin studio? If Yes, can I have a sample or a reference or an idea about how can be done?
Thx